Who is the inventor of game of dice, according to our scriptures?
In this chapter of Sabha Parva, Duryodhana says:-

"Duryodhana replied,--'Men of the most ancient times invented the use of dice. There is no destruction in it, nor is there any striking with, weapons. Let the words of Sakuni, therefore, be acceptable to thee, and let thy command be issued for the speedy construction of the assembly house. The door of heaven, leading us to such happiness, will be opened to us by gambling. Indeed, they that betake to gambling (with such aid) deserve such good fortune. The Pandavas then will become thy equals (instead of, as now, superiors); therefore, gamble thou with the Pandavas.

I want to know who invented the dice game. So my question is, Who is inventor of game of dice? Does any scripture mention anything about them?
